# Cannot find image on Linux system

Tags: css, linux, image

Linux System.
There are many images at `web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images`

```
web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images/a.jpg
web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images/b.jpg
web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images/c.jpg
```

When I click `www.mywebsite.com/_assets/desktop/common/images/`

I can see list of 3 images.I can even access to

```
www.mywebsite.com/_assets/desktop/common/images/a.jpg
www.mywebsite.com/_assets/desktop/common/images/b.jpg
www.mywebsite.com/_assets/desktop/common/images/c.jpg
```

I added one more image

```
web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images/d.jpg
```

but I cannot access the new image in the list
neither can I access to the link

```
www.mywebsite.com/_assets/desktop/common/images/d.jpg
```

What can be the reason for not display the image ? The same works fine on Windows System

Comment: What server system are you using? Just because all of the files exist on the system doesn't mean that your server exposes it in a URL.

Comment: Linux System. Its a web project. The image folder is in web/webroot folder

Answer (score 0):

This may be permission issue. Please check the image file permission.

//Commands to check this,

```
cd   web/webroot/_assets/desktop/common/images/

ll   d.jpg
```

//Change the permission of this image file as others(using 'chmod' command ).

Hope this would be helpful for you.